# How can I directly handle excel-file-link PYTHOn

Tags: python, pandas

Say there is a `excel-file` link as `http://www.gstatic.com/adwords-scripty/account_upload_template.xlsx`

And I want to parse excel file then save data into db after request the link.

I tried with `pandas.read_excel()` but failed. Sorry I'm new to `pandas`

How can I make it as expected.

```
excel_url = "http://www.gstatic.com/adwords-scripty/account_upload_template.xlsx"

csv_url = "http://www.gstatic.com/adwords-scripty/account_upload_template.csv"

import csv
import requests
import pandas as pd

from requests.sessions import Session
s = Session()

with s.get(excel_url) as res:
    r = pd.read_excel(res.text)
    print(r)
```

Comment: What output do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `read_excel` expects a stream or file-like object and not a string.  Second, `text` is going to decode the Excel bytes as UTF8 and that isn't neccesarily safe.  Try this:

```
excel_url = "http://www.gstatic.com/adwords-scripty/account_upload_template.xlsx"

csv_url = "http://www.gstatic.com/adwords-scripty/account_upload_template.csv"

import io
import csv
import requests
import pandas as pd

from requests.sessions import Session
s = Session()

with s.get(excel_url) as res:
    file_like = io.BytesIO(res.content)
    r = pd.read_excel(file_like)
    print(r)
```

Comment: Actually.  For clarity's sake.  `read_excel` can take in a string but it assumes that string is a path and not the contents of a file.  Also, `text` will try and guess the encoding and not just default to UTF8.

Comment: Also, you can just do `r = pd.read_excel(excel_url)` and save yourself a lot of trouble.